# Unexpectedly large cmem[2] usage in CUDA code

Tags: optimization, cuda, gpu

I'm writing an (admittedly local memory-intensive) code on CUDA and am past the development phase and into acceleration. The command line profiler indicates that my occupancies are (I think) very low (0.083 - 0.417 for major kernels) and I would like to improve this. The computational work unfortunately requires a large amount of `__shared__` memory (16-20 kB per 128-thread block) and some registers (reported for major kernels as 63, although I'm not sure that I'm actually using this many...)

My real question though, has to do with `cmem[2]`. Here's an example:

> Used 8 registers, 40 bytes cmem[0], 51584 bytes cmem[2], 368 bytes cmem[14], 4 bytes cmem[16]

All kernels seem to use this large amount of `cmem[2]`, and I'm not even sure what it is. I store plenty of memory on the device with the usual `cudaMalloc` calls, and a handful of doubles and pointers in `__constant__` memory via `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` calls (nowhere near 50 kB, though), but that's about it. So my question is: How exactly could I be using all this `cmem[2]`, and is it limiting my kernel occupancy?

Also, I'm running on a GTX 550 Ti with CUDA 4.2 and Ubuntu 10.04.4 64 bit. The nvcc-made executable is wrapped in mpirun, since the code is also MPI parallelized.

Comment: Have you looked at the PTX output from the kernel compilation (`nvcc -ptx`)? That might give you some hint.

Comment: Do your kernels have a lot of parameters or complex struct parameters? Can you provide at least the prototype for one of the kernels with large cmem usage?  Also the nvcc command line used to compile.

Answer (score 3):

On the Fermi architecture the CUDA driver uses cmem[2] for storage of **constant** variables. All functions in the same module share the same constants. The size of this constant bank will not impact your theoretical SM occupancy or increase your launch overhead. If you exceed the maximum size (64KB) you should receive a compiler error.

The CUDA binary utility cuobjdump can be used to debug the allocations.

If you have the file sm20.cu with the following constants

```
__constant__ float k_float_array[] = { 0.f, 1.f, 2.f, 3.f };
__constant__ double k_double_array[] = { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
__constant__ int k_int_array[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

__global__ void empty_kernel(float* a)
{
    return;
}
```

You can run

```
cuobjdump.exe -elf sm20.cu.obj
```

The executable can also be used as the argument. Run cuobjdump --help to get a list of the options.

This command will produce the following output

```
Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_20
code version = [1,5]
producer = cuda
host = windows
compile_size = 32bit
identifier = c:/dev/constant/sm20.cu

32bit elf: abi=5, sm=20, flags = 0x140114
Sections:
Index Offset   Size ES Align   Type   Flags Link     Info Name
    1     34     a6  0  1    STRTAB       0    0        0 .shstrtab
    2     da     e9  0  1    STRTAB       0    0        0 .strtab
    3    1c4     80 10  4    SYMTAB       0    2        6 .symtab
    4    244     18  0  4 CUDA_INFO       0    3        0 .nv.info
    5    25c     20  0  4 CUDA_INFO       0    3        8 .nv.info._Z12empty_kernelPf
    6    27c     24  0  4  PROGBITS       2    0        8 .nv.constant0._Z12empty_kernelPf
    7    2a0     40  0  8  PROGBITS       2    0        0 .nv.constant2
    8    2e0     10  0  4  PROGBITS       6    3  2000007 .text._Z12empty_kernelPf
```

The elf section .nv.constant2 contains the contents of cmem[2]. This size is 0x40 == 64 bytes which matches my expectations.

.nv.constant2 is section index 7.

```
.section .strtab

.section .shstrtab

.section .symtab
 index     value     size      info    other  shndx    name
   0          0        0        0        0      0     (null)
   1          0        0        3        0      8     .text._Z12empty_kernelPf
   2          0        0        3        0      6     .nv.constant0._Z12empty_kernelPf
   3          0        0        3        0      7     .nv.constant2
   4          0       16        1        0      7     k_float_array
   5         16       32        1        0      7     k_double_array
   6         48       16        1        0      7     k_int_array
   7          0       16       12       10      8     _Z12empty_kernelPf
```

The .symtab contains the 3 constant arrays defined. All symbols with shndx == 7 will be in .nv.constant2

```
.nv.constant0._Z12empty_kernelPf
0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000

.nv.constant2
0x00000000  0x3f800000  0x40000000  0x40400000  0x00000000
0x00000000  0x00000000  0x3ff00000  0x00000000
0x40000000  0x00000000  0x40080000  0x00000000
0x00000001  0x00000002  0x00000003
```

.nv.constant2 defines the binary data in the section. This matches the declared constant variables. If you have a lot of constants the .symtab section identifies the offset and size of each of the symbols.

```
// skipping .nv.info and .text
```

cuobjdump can be used to dump the PTX and SASS code. PTX and SASS assembly can be used to determine what kernels are using constants.